# C# generic typing with multiple class constraints

Tags: c#

**TL;DR**

I'd like this to compile in C#

`public void some_method< T >() where T : class1, class2`

Is this possible?

---

**Full Context**

I have two methods that are identical except for **one** parameter.

```
public SignInResponseMessage Generate(SignInRequestMessage request, (X509Certificate2 || WindowsPrincipal) principal, Uri requestUri)
{
    SignInResponseMessage response = null;
    ClaimsIdentity identity = null;

    if (principal != null)
    {
        identity = CreateSubject(principal);
        response = Generate(request, requestUri, identity);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("principal");
    }

    return response;
}
```

I'm currently replicating this method and it's making me cringe a little inside as I would really like to make this `DRY`-er. Looking around, [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_0) seemed promising, but it only allows me to add a single class constraint. I get the following error on the second class:

> Error 1   The class type constraint 'class2' must come before any other constraints

If `WindowsPrincipal` and `X509Certificate2` were two classes I had written I could easily make them implement the same interface and I would be good to go, but that's not an option.

**Is there any way to accomplish what I'd like to do?**

If not, **I'd like to know more about the underlying mechanism that makes this impossible**.

Comment: This isn't possible.  A potential solution is to use the Adapter pattern where your adapter implements your interface and then use your interface as the constraint.

Comment: Do you have a good resource for the adapter pattern? That's a new one for me

Comment: The Gang of Four have described it well.  You can use resources like the following: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Adapter.aspx

Comment: C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so you can't use two classes as a type constraint.

Comment: You could do `where T : class1, interface2` or `where T : class, interface1, interface2`. Then by setting up your interfaces cleverly, you could get close to what you want.

Comment: @Matt this is the strategy pattern, not the adapter pattern. Adapter is to make one type fit into an existing framework. Strategy is the ability to substitute implementations at runtime.
http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am afraid that this could lead to issues with working out what method to actually call. Imagine if one of the classes specified inherited from the other and there was an override for that method!?

[Please see the "Diamond Problem" for a complete description of the reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)

If you want to work around it. You can set up the common shared interface with an adapter and then use that.

```
interface IAdaper {
    SomeMethod();
}

class AdapterOne : IAdapter {
    TypeOneToCall  _one;

    public AdapterOne (TypeOneToCall one) {
        _one = one;
    }

    public SomeMethod() {
        return _one.SomeMethod();
    }
}

class AdapterTwo : IAdapter {
    TypeTwoToCall _two;

    public AdapterTwo (TypeTwoToCall two) {
        _two = two;
    }

    public SomeMethod() {
        return _two.SomeMethod();
    }
}

class Generic<T> where T : IAdapter {

    // Your implementation here.
}
```

Comment: Makes sense for calling methods, but what prevents a feature like this from existing in this particular use case - where an object is passed along to an overloaded method that actually does something different?
I.e. Is there a reason the compiler cannott only verify `T` is the proper type (and disallow any methods be called on `T` in that method)?

Comment: If one class inherited from another there wouldn't be a problem, the extra constraint on the base class would just be redundant.

Comment: The suggestion to create an abstraction (`IAdapter`) is a good idea. In this case, you don't even need the `Generic` class to be generic since it doesn't need to know what is behind `IAdapter`.

Comment: Also the designers of C# are all about consistency and I personally tend to agree with them. If it doesn't work nicely in all cases, it tends to get left out.

Comment: This is really the strategy pattern, not the adapter pattern, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn how will the Strategy pattern solve for generic constraints?  I disagree, I still believe the adapter pattern is the right way to solve this.  This posted answer is a blend of both patterns I think, but the core root is being able to transform it into a common interface.

Comment: @DavidL The generic constraint is no longer necessary, as Yacoub noted.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn true, I missed his comment.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars do you have a link to a blog post or something to that effect, seems like it would be an interesting read

Comment: @Matt, the method call would look like `public SignInResponseMessage Generate(SignInRequestMessage request, IAdapter principal, Uri requestUri)` instead of being a generic method.

Comment: @Matt, the strategy pattern is subtle, but super-powerful. This is a pretty good example. The idea is that the behavior is changed at runtime, instead of specified at compile time.
https://dotnetfreakblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/strategy-design-pattern-using-c/

Comment: I have used this pattern for all sorts of applications. Also similar things for dealing with statics in a DI.This is very related to the strategy pattern. The IAdapter is a sort of strategy.

Answer (score 6):

If you pass the method as a parameter, then T can be anything:

```
  public SignInResponseMessage Generate<T>(SignInRequestMessage request, 
                                          Func<T, ClaimsIdentity> createSubject, 
                                          T principal, 
                                          Uri requestUri)
  {
      SignInResponseMessage response = null;
      ClaimsIdentity identity = null;

      if (principal != null)
      {
          identity = createSubject(principal);
          response = Generate(request, requestUri, identity);
      }
      else
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("principal");
      }

      return response;
  }
```

So to reuse the method:

```
  var r1 = Generate<X509Certificate2>(request, CreateSubject, certificate, uri);
  var r2 = Generate<WindowsPrincipal>(request, CreateSubject, principal, uri);
```

Comment: This is definitely slicker and works, but I tend to avoid delegates as they make the code more confusing to read

Comment: This is a very functional approach. Done right it can be just as clean and readable as any OO pattern. Plus less code. Don't write it off too easy.

Comment: I disagree with my past self; this is a good approach.