# C# duplicate generic class declaration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, .net-8.0

The following code is considered a duplicate class declaration by the compiler.

I assume this is because the order of the type arguments in the class declarations is ignored, but I'm struggling to find documentation to confirm this.
I assumed that it would behave in the same way as a method overload where the order of the parameters would be enough to differentiate the two classes.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case?

```
public abstract class SubProcess<TSubProcessParameters, TInitialState> : SubProcess<TInitialState> 
    where TInitialState : IState 
    where TSubProcessParameters : class, new()
{
    ///
}

//type argument order is different to the class above
public abstract class SubProcess<TInitialState, TSubProcessReturnValues> : SubProcess<TInitialState> 
    where TInitialState : IState 
    where TSubProcessReturnValues : class, new()
{    
    ///
}
```

Comment: The type parameters are placeholders. The same types could be given to both classes, and that would create ambiguity.

Comment: The constraints make no difference, because the same type could comply with both constraints.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749666/c-sharp-generic-typing-with-multiple-class-constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are looking for the documentation, it is mentioned in the C# specification, [Basic concepts - Declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#73-declarations):

> Two or more type declarations with the same name but distinct numbers of type parameters are allowed in the same declaration space ([§7.8.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#782-unqualified-names)).

So, constraints are not considered.

Answer (score 2):

The two types declarations have the same *unqualified name*, and because they are in the same namespace, they also have the same *fully-qualified name*, and that is not allowed.

[Unqualified Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#782-unqualified-names):

> For a type declaration with K type parameters, the unqualified name is the identifier specified in the declaration, followed by the generic_dimension_specifier ([§12.8.17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12817-the-typeof-operator)) for K type parameters.

So the unqualified name for both classes is `SubProcess<,,>`.

The [fully qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#783-fully-qualified-names) for them is just the unqualified name with their namespace appended to it. This is not allowed:

> It is an error for a type declaration without the `partial` modifier to have the same fully qualified name as another type declaration.

Intuitively, two generic type declarations that only differ in the type constraints is not allowed because it would create lots of ambiguities. If `A` and `B` both implement `IState`, are classes, and have a parameterless constructor, which type declaration does `SubProcess<A, B>` refer to?

Also, what `Type` would the expression `typeof(SubProcess<,,>)` evaluate to?

> I assumed that it would behave in the same way as a method overload

No, [method overloading doesn't support overloading with different type constraints either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359262/5133585).

Answer (score 1):

```
class StateImplementation : IState {}

class CrashAndBurn : SubProcess<StateImplementation, StateImplementation> {}
```

If you can tell me which of your classes the compiler should pick, you may be onto something :)

Yes, they are duplicates. Your compiler is correct. There is really nothing more to say. Pick different names or just delete one.